# Why is my code debugging without finishing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, debugging, neural-network

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import random

"""
def func(data):   #labels our train data
    train_labels = []
    i = 1
    for pt in data:
        if pt[0] > pt[1]:
            train_labels.append(1)
        else:
            train_labels.append(-1)

    return train_labels
        #print("{}. Punkt = {}".format(i, x))
        #i += 1
"""

def activation(input):
    if input >= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1


class Model:

    def __init__(self, nweights=1):
        self.nweights = nweights

    def setweights(self):
        self.weights = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(self.nweights, 1))
        return self.weights

    def guess(self, input):
        sum = 0;
        i = 0;
        while i < len(self.weights):
            sum += input[i] * self.weights[i]
        return func(sum)

train_data = np.random.randint(100, size=(1, 2))

brain = Model(1)
brain.setweights()
brain.guess(train_data)
```

Hey there, 
I have got a little problem with my code as it's just loading but I don't get any results. So it starts debugging but I don't get any errors or results, it just debugs without finishing. The problem can't be led back to any hardware issues, so it must have something to do with my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't increment i` in your `while i < ...` loop, hence it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `guess` function gets stuck in an infinite loop, since you never *increment* `i`.

```
def guess(self, input):
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(self.weights)):
        sum += input[i] * self.weights[i]
    return func(sum)
```